# CakePHP4: Concatenated where on connected table not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, search, cakephp

I got the following scenario.

Software: Current CakePHP 4 Beta (Commit 48c3f80f8f)

## The SQL for the tables

Lets image we have 2 Tables.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customers;
CREATE TABLE customers
(
    id             INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    company        VARCHAR(255),
    first_name     VARCHAR(255),
    last_name      VARCHAR(255),
    created        DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    modified       DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
  COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customers_contacts;
CREATE TABLE customers_contacts
(
    id             INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    company        VARCHAR(255),
    first_name     VARCHAR(255),
    last_name      VARCHAR(255),
    customers_id   INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    created        DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    modified       DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
  COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And therefore we have a one to many connection between customers and customers_contacts

```
// CustomersTable.php
$this->hasMany( 'CustomersContacts', [
  'foreignKey' => 'customers_id'
] );

// CustomersContactsTable.php
$this->belongsTo( 'Customers', [
  'foreignKey' => 'customers_id'
] );
```

## The Search Implementation

The first step was to implement a search where i can not only search for single column values but also for concatenated columns like "firstname lastname" or "lastname firstname"

### This works

I did accomplish that with the following code inside my index function

```
$query = $this->Customers->find( 'all' )
                                  ->contain( ['CustomersContacts'] );
$current_request = $this->getRequest();

$search = $current_request->getQuery( 'search' );

// Default cake sort by clicking on table head
$sort_dir = $current_request->getQuery( 'direction' );
$sort_col = $current_request->getQuery( 'sort' );

if ( $current_request->is( 'get' ) ) {
  // Default sort by modified date
  if ( $sort_dir == '' && $sort_col == '' ) {
    $query->orderDesc( 'Customers.modified' );
  }

  // Change query if a search parameter is given in GET data
  if ( $search ) {

    // Search for concat fields in cakephp >=3
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405261/search-with-concat-fields-in-cakephp-3
    $query->where( function( $exp, $q ) use ( $search ) {
      /**
        * @var QueryExpression $exp
        * @var Query $q
        */

      // Concatenated Customers Name
      $conc1 = $q->func()
                  ->concat( [
                              'Customers.first_name' => 'literal',
                              ' ',
                              'Customers.last_name' => 'literal'
                            ] );
      $conc2 = $q->func()
                  ->concat( [
                              'Customers.last_name' => 'literal',
                              ' ',
                              'Customers.first_name' => 'literal'
                            ] );

      return $exp->or( [
                          'Customers.company LIKE' => "%$search%",
                          'Customers.first_name LIKE' => "%$search%",
                          'Customers.last_name LIKE' => "%$search%",
                        ] )
                  ->like( $conc1, "%$search%" )
                  ->like( $conc2, "%$search%" );
    } );

    $current_request = $current_request->withData( 'search', $search );
    $this->setRequest( $current_request );
  }
}

$Customers = $this->paginate( $query );

$this->set( compact( 'Customers' ) );
```

### This doesn't work

Then I thought i can enhance the search by also adding the first and last name of the connected customers contacts table with the following code:

```
$query = $this->Customers->find( 'all' )
                                  ->contain( ['CustomersContacts'] );
$current_request = $this->getRequest();

$search = $current_request->getQuery( 'search' );

// Default cake sort by clicking on table head
$sort_dir = $current_request->getQuery( 'direction' );
$sort_col = $current_request->getQuery( 'sort' );

if ( $current_request->is( 'get' ) ) {
  // Default sort by modified date
  if ( $sort_dir == '' && $sort_col == '' ) {
    $query->orderDesc( 'Customers.modified' );
  }

  // Change query if a search parameter is given in GET data
  if ( $search ) {

    // Search for concat fields in cakephp >=3
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405261/search-with-concat-fields-in-cakephp-3
    $query->where( function( $exp, $q ) use ( $search ) {
      /**
        * @var QueryExpression $exp
        * @var Query $q
        */

      // Concatenated Customers Name
      $conc1 = $q->func()
                  ->concat( [
                              'Customers.first_name' => 'literal',
                              ' ',
                              'Customers.last_name' => 'literal'
                            ] );
      $conc2 = $q->func()
                  ->concat( [
                              'Customers.last_name' => 'literal',
                              ' ',
                              'Customers.first_name' => 'literal'
                            ] );

      // Concatenated CustomersContacts Name
      $conc3 = $q->func()
                  ->concat( [
                              'CustomersContacts.first_name' => 'literal',
                              ' ',
                              'CustomersContacts.last_name' => 'literal'
                            ] );
      $conc4 = $q->func()
                  ->concat( [
                              'CustomersContacts.last_name' => 'literal',
                              ' ',
                              'CustomersContacts.first_name' => 'literal'
                            ] );

      return $exp->or( [
                          'Customers.company LIKE' => "%$search%",
                          'Customers.first_name LIKE' => "%$search%",
                          'Customers.last_name LIKE' => "%$search%",
                          'CustomersContacts.first_name LIKE' => "%$search%",
                          'CustomersContacts.last_name LIKE' => "%$search%"
                        ] )
                  ->like( $conc1, "%$search%" )
                  ->like( $conc2, "%$search%" )
                  ->like( $conc3, "%$search%" )
                  ->like( $conc4, "%$search%" );
    } );

    $current_request = $current_request->withData( 'search', $search );
    $this->setRequest( $current_request );
  }
}

$Customers = $this->paginate( $query );

$this->set( compact( 'Customers' ) );
```

## The error

But now when I perform a search I get the following error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'CustomersContacts.first_name' in 'where clause'
```

Which I don't really get, because the join between Customers and CustomersContacts should have happened with the

```
->contain( ['CustomersContacts'] );
```

But this doesn't seem to be the case, because in the Debug Kit I checked the SQL Query and there is no Join between Contacts and ContactsCustomers.

## What am I expecting

So the result im expecting is to show all the customers, which have related customers contacts, where the given search term has something to do with first or last name of these customers contacts.

Is that possible with this approach or do I have to go another way with that?

Comment: With a `hasMany` association, the related records are loaded with a separate query instead of a join. To do what you want, you're going to need to use `matching` on your contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got what i was looking for with this code:

```
// Had to remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from sql_mode so the distinct works
$query = $this->Customers->find( 'all' )
                         ->distinct( ['id'] )
                         ->contain( ['CustomersContacts'] );

// Check all the "matching" CustomersContacts if they have something in common with the given search parameter
// We have to use matching() instead of where() because we have a 1:N connection between Customers and CustomersContacts
$query->matching( 'CustomersContacts', function( $q ) use ( $search ) {
  /**
    * @var Query $q
    */
  return $q->where( function( $exp, $q ) use ( $search ) {
    /**
      * @var QueryExpression $exp
      * @var Query $q
      */

    $conc1 = $q->func()
                ->concat( [
                            'Customers.first_name' => 'literal',
                            ' ',
                            'Customers.last_name' => 'literal'
                          ] );
    $conc2 = $q->func()
                ->concat( [
                            'Customers.last_name' => 'literal',
                            ' ',
                            'Customers.first_name' => 'literal'
                          ] );

    // Concatenated CustomersContacts Name
    $conc3 = $q->func()
                ->concat( [
                            'CustomersContacts.first_name' => 'literal',
                            ' ',
                            'CustomersContacts.last_name' => 'literal'
                          ] );
    $conc4 = $q->func()
                ->concat( [
                            'CustomersContacts.last_name' => 'literal',
                            ' ',
                            'CustomersContacts.first_name' => 'literal'
                          ] );

    return $exp->or( [
                        'Customers.company LIKE' => "%$search%",
                        'Customers.first_name LIKE' => "%$search%",
                        'Customers.last_name LIKE' => "%$search%",
                        'Customers.city LIKE' => "%$search%",
                        'CustomersContacts.first_name LIKE' => "%$search%",
                        'CustomersContacts.last_name LIKE' => "%$search%"
                      ] )
                ->like( $conc1, "%$search%" )
                ->like( $conc2, "%$search%" )
                ->like( $conc3, "%$search%" )
                ->like( $conc4, "%$search%" );
  } );
} );
```

Thanks again to Greg Schmidt for the notice about `matching`